# как передать значение из кнопки в модальное окно с activeForm yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет подскажите пожалуйста
в task/index у меня рендерится список задач и в нем есть колонка с выпадающим списком кнопок в которой есть кнопка выполнить задачу

```
[
                            'class' => ActionColumn::class,
                            'template' => '{all}',
                            'buttons' => [
                                'all' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                                    return ButtonDropdown::widget([
                                        'encodeLabel' => false,
                                        'label' => '<span class="fas fa-bars"></span>',
                                        'dropdown' => [
                                            'encodeLabels' => false,
                                            'items' => [

                                                [
                                                    'label' => '<span class="fa fa-pencil-alt text-primary"></span> &nbsp; Изменить',
                                                    'url' => ['update', 'id' => $key],
                                                    'visible' => true,
                                                ],
                                                [
                                                    'label' => Html::a('<i class="fa fa-check-circle">Выполнить</i>', ['#'],
                                                        [
                                                            'title' => 'Выполнить задачу',
                                                            'class' => 'resultBtn btn btn-success',
                                                            'data-toggle' => 'modal',
                                                            'data-target' => '#result',
                                                            'data-id' => $key
                                                        ]),
                                                    'visible' => true,
                                                ],
                                            ],
                                            'options' => [
                                                'class' => 'dropdown-menu-right',
                                            ],
                                        ],
                                        'options' => [
                                            'class' => 'btn-default',
                                        ],
                                        'split' => true,
                                    ]);
                                },

                            ],
```

далее эта кнопка вызывает модальное окно в котором есть input,в который вводится результат выполнения задачи

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
'size' => 'modal-lg',
'options' => [
'id' => 'result'
],
'closeButton' => ['tag' => 'button', 'label' => 'x',],
'title' => '<h2>Введите результат задачи</h2>',
]);
?>
<?php
ActiveForm::begin([
'method' => 'post',
'action' => ['archive',]
]);
echo '<div class="input-group input-group-md">';
    echo html::input(
    'text',
    'result',
    '',
    [
    'placeholder' => 'Введите результат...',
    'class' => 'form-control'
    ]
    );
    echo '<span class="input-group-btn">';
    echo html::submitButton(
    '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>',
    [
        'class' => 'btn btn-success',
    ]
);
echo '</span></div>';
ActiveForm::end();
?>
<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

мне нужно id задачи передать в конртоллер

```
public function actionArchive($id)
    {
        $resultVal = Yii::$app->request->post('result');
        $estateObject = $this->findModel($id);
        $estateObject->updateAttributes(['finishedAt' => time()]);
        $estateObject->updateAttributes(['isArchive' => 1]);
        $estateObject->updateAttributes(['result' => $resultVal]);

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

в общем нужно чтобы тут`ActiveForm::begin([ 'method' => 'post', 'action' => ['archive','id' => id задачи на которую нажали] ]);` было значение

или же как то сделать так чтобы id передать из кнопки в модалку через js записать в переменную и потом уже submitbutton при клике делать ajax и чтобы урл был `task/archive?id=(и тут переменная)`

Answer (score 0):

Ты 'result' получаешь из ajax запроса? Если да, то:

```
ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'formGetResult'
    'method' => 'post',
    'action' => ''
    ]);
```

потом средствами jqury меняешь урл у формы (находишь ее по ID), и отправляешь данные